# Clojure : call a java subclass of abstract class

Tags: java, clojure, subclass

I have a problem today because I do not know how to call a java class which extends a sublass. I know there is the $ sign for nested class but here I'm lost.

To be more clear, here are the classes :

Abstract class :

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fitting/AbstractCurveFitter.html

Subclass :

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fitting/SimpleCurveFitter.html

To be honest, I forgot a lot of thing about java but I see there is no constructor for the subclass. The problem is that I must use the sublass.

Here is the code

```
(defn apache-logistic-reg [data x0 lamb]
  (let [f (Logistic$Parametric.)
        start (def-start x0 lamb)
        fitter (.create SimpleCurveFitter. f start)
        points (double-array (extract-points data))]
    (.fit fitter points)))
```

The problem is that I cannot call SimpleCurveFitter. because it has no constructor. And AbstractCurveFitter has no .create, plus if I remember it well abstract classes cannot be cast.

And if I remember well, the constructor of SimpleCurveFitter would have the name of its abstract class but maybe I'm wrong.

How can I do ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call a constructor in `SimpleCurveFitter`, because it provides the static method `create` to get an instance for you (which you're already trying to use). Just make a static method call to that method to get an instance:

```lisp
(.create SimpleCurveFitter  f start) ;; No '.' after SimpleCurveFitter
(. SimpleCurveFitter create f start) ;; Alternate syntax
(SimpleCurveFitter/create   f start) ;; Most common syntax (pointed out by amalloy)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally it was "simple" like String and so on, I imagined harder manipulations !

Comment: The third syntax here is by far the most typical one to use for calling static methods.